# How to prevent This PC node from automatically expanding when I open File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-8.1

How do I prevent the "This PC" node from automatically expanding each time I open Windows Explorer/File Explorer on Windows?

There must be a registry key somewhere, but I cannot find it.

---

I have tried opening Explorer, going to `View` > `Options` > `Folder Options` > `General` > Uncheck "Automatically expand to current folder", but that option was already unchecked.

Comment: I have been searching for a way to do this too - frustratingly, I don't think there is a way. I'd love to be corrected!